# Testcafe - sending false errors/dies after running 100+ tests in a row

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am creating an automation testing platform, and I wrote a code which executes around 300+ tests in a row.
I am currently running the tests on my local machine. After around 10-20 tests the testcafe either stops working or giving false error or starts slowing down and not navigating to the right page therefore can't find any of the selectors I tell it to look for.

I know this to be false errors since when I only run these tests on their own testcafe is not doing that anymore and the tests pass successfully with no errors at all.

Any idea whats going on? Is this a problem with my local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the issue in my code. I took a lot of screenshots per test and didn't clear them after each run which inflated my memory causing node and testcafe to crash.
Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the issue is unclear. Please create a separate issue using the following link https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml and share an example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.